# How to add library retrofit in android?

Tags: android

I want to add retrofit in my android but when I want to add this library my android take error and this is my **error:**

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0.
```

and my app module **code** is below:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mahdi.chatapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and my build project code is **below:**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I was able to download the 2.5.0 version. Check your internet speed and try again.

Comment: add  jcenter() in both repositories blocks in project level gradle files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is because the `2.5.0` version is not signed. If you see in jcenter http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/retrofit2/retrofit/2.5.0/ the files are not signed `.asc` extension. If you check version [2.4.0](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/retrofit2/retrofit/2.4.0/)

Try this:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

If you also want rxJava converter use:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: yeah but I am able to import and use 2.5.0 without any issues...I think there is something wrong with his Gradle files or he encountered some network issue during sync

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that my gradle was offline work

Answer (score 2):

Go to File ⇒ New Project. When it prompts you to select the default activity, select Empty Activity and proceed.
Open `build.gradle` in (Module `:app`) and add `Retrofit`, `Picasso`, `RecyclerView`, `Gson` dependencies like this.

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in app level build.gradle file:

`implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'`

For further details, you can visit on this [link](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).